# Where can I safely store my stuff in Turdograd?

Tags: atom-rpg-trudograd

Where is a safe place that I can use to store my stuff as I go through the game?  I haven't come across any base or player owned property so far that I can call my own and I'm starting to get weighed down with a few heavy things that I want to keep for later (mostly exo suit parts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing through the game, I've found that the best place to store stuff is the closet in the room where you begin the game in the Turdograd outskirts.

However, there is a certain point to be aware of:

> After a point of no return near the end of the game, the game world state will change and you will no longer have access to that closet.